# How to convert a specific character string to datetime?

Tags: r

How do I convert the below character string to datetime in RStudio?

`2018-02-01T12:40:04`

Answer (score 4):

We can keep the `T` also in the `format`

```
as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2018-02-01 12:40:04 EST"
```

---

Or use `ymd_hms` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(str1)
```

---

Or use `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime(str1)
#[1] "2018-02-01 12:40:04 EST"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2018-02-01T12:40:04"
```